# Remove anything between first two dashes MySQL

Tags: mysql

Good day, I just wanted to ask a help for a select query to select some characters but removing anything between two dashes, for example:

```
011-12-004 , 011-32-003-B
```

to

```
011004 , 011003-B
```

All I can do is remove from one dash. Please help me.

Comment: Wait, in your second string there are 3 dashes, why should `-003-` not be removed? Or the whole `-32-003-`?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: only -32- which is in the first two dashes should be removed. @ALFA

Comment: @Strawberry I tried trims, replace and substring_index but I am too far from what I've wanted

Comment: Substring_index sounds like one way - although for more complex manipulations , you might do better with application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how to differentiate -32- from -003-, I'm guessing you should replace a pattern that matches `-(number here)-`.

In `MySQL 8.0` you can use [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) function.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(text,'-[0-9]+-','',1,0,'c') FROM your_table;
```

the output will be:

```
011004
011003-B
```

Comment: too bad the mysql version we used is 5.7 :( but this answer is really appreciated

Comment: Take a look at https://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/, I didn't test it but it could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be quite right, but close enough...

```
SET @s = '011-12-004 , 011-32-003-B';
SELECT CONCAT(MID(@s,1,CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@s,'-',1))),MID(@s,CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@s,'-',2))+2,1000))x;

+-----------------------+
| x                     |
+-----------------------+
| 011004 , 011-32-003-B |
+-----------------------+
```